# How to drag and drop files into QListWidget created from Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, designer, qlistwidget

I'm fairly new to using Qt and started by using Qt Designer to generate the .ui file.  This question is focused on just a QListWidget I have.  I want to be able to drag files (.obj/.fbx files) from an opened instance of Windows Explorer and drop them into my QListWidget and once I drop the file, a function is called to add the item to the list.

This is a section of my .ui file that contains the QListWidget

```
<widget class="QListWidget" name="LIST_MyFiles">
 <property name="sizePolicy">
  <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
   <horstretch>0</horstretch>
   <verstretch>0</verstretch>
  </sizepolicy>
 </property>
 <property name="minimumSize">
  <size>
   <width>650</width>
   <height>0</height>
  </size>
 </property>
 <property name="maximumSize">
  <size>
   <width>650</width>
   <height>300</height>
  </size>
 </property>
 <property name="dragDropOverwriteMode">
  <bool>false</bool>
 </property>
 <property name="dragDropMode">
  <enum>QAbstractItemView::DropOnly</enum>
 </property>
</widget>
```

In my actual .py file, I have this chunk which starts things off

```
    from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, QtUiTools
    class MyTestClass(QtWidgets.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MyTestClass, self).__init__(parent)
    
            filePath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
            uiFileLocation = r"%s\\ui\\myDesignerUI.ui" % filePath
            uiFile = QtCore.QFile(uiFileLocation)
            uiFile.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
            uiFile.close()
    
            # Load the created UI widget from Designer
            self.widget = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load(ui_file)
    
            # Attach the widget to the "self" GUI
            self.widget.setParent(self)
            self.createConnections() # This simply sets up the .connect event when user clicks on some buttons in the ui.
```

I have seen some online examples of how to do this, but in all those examples, the QListWidget is being created in its own class in the Python file, whereas mine is created in Qt Designer and stored in a .ui file.

Can anyone provide some examples when using Qt Designer to make the ui so that I can drag and drop files from Explorer into my QListWidget LIST_MyFiles?

Comment: If the ui file only has the QListWidget, there's no need for that. Otherwise you can promote the QListWidget to a custom class. Look for resources about "promoted widgets" or "widget promotion".

Comment: So I dug a bit into promoting widgets in Qt Designer and I think I get the high level gist whereby the QListWidget I make in Designer is a placeholder and promoting it simply means that this widget gets 'replaced' by a QtWidgets.QListWidget class in another python file.  I'm trying to figure out the exact steps to set everything up.  Is this page https://www.py4u.net/discuss/145409 reliable to refer to (seems old) or are there any walkthroughs/tutorials that would be better to look at?

Comment: Yes, the placeholder is then "replaced" by a custom subclass (which has to be of the same type). Do a google search on StackOverflow about that, you'll see plenty of related questions, most of them with answer that better explain how it works and how can be implemented: "site:stackoverflow.com pyqt promoting widget"